# SCRIPT para Converter e Salvar Endereços

Tags: php, cakephp, http, google, cakephp-2

Desenvolvi em uma API REST com CakePHP um script para converter uma coordenada `$lat` e `$lng` em endereços formatados. O script verifica se a coordenada está salva no banco, caso negativo ela busca do google e já salva no banco.

O script tem funcionado normalmente, segue script abaixo:

**GEOCODES CONTROLLER**

```
        // Function to serialize array $response to the format requested
        public function beforeRender() {
            $this->set('_serialize', 'response');
        }
        public function index(){
            //$functions = new GeocodeFunctions();
            //$latlng = $functions->verificaLatLng($this->request->query['latlng']);
            $response = $this->requestAction(
                array('controller' => 'geocodes', 'action' => 'geocode'),
                array('pass' => array($this->request->query['latlng']))
            );
            $this->set('response',$response);
        }
        public function geocode($latlng = null) {
            $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource("geocode");
            $functions = new GeocodeFunctions();
            //$latlng = $functions->verificaLatLng($latlng);
            if($latlng != null){
                $geocode = $db->fetchAll(
                    'Select enderecos.endereco as endereco from geocodes inner join enderecos on geocodes.id_endereco = enderecos.id where geocodes.latlng like ? ;'
                    ,array($latlng)
                );
                if(empty($geocode)){
                    $google = $this->google($latlng, $db);
                    if(array_key_exists('results',$google) && $google->results != array()){
                        $response = array('code'=>2, 'endereco'=>$google->results[0]->formatted_address);   
                    }else if(array_key_exists('error_message',$google)){
                        $response = array('code'=>3, 'endereco'=>'O seguinte erro ocorreu "'.$google->error_message.'", por favor informe ao suporte do ocorrido.');
                    }else{
                        $response = array('code'=>3, 'endereco'=>'Novo erro detectado! Por favor, entre em contato com o suporte informando dia e hora do ocorrido.');  
                        CakeLog::write('geocodes', json_encode($google));
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $response= array('code'=>1, 'endereco'=>$geocode[0]['enderecos']['endereco']);
                }
            }
            else{
                $response = array('code'=>0, 'endereco'=>'latitude e longitudade vazia!');
            }
            return $response;
        }

        public function google($latlng = null, $db){
                $data = array();
                if($latlng != null){
                    $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
                    $results = $HttpSocket->get(
                    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', 
                       array(
                        'latlng' => $latlng, 
                        'key' => 'minha-chave-secreta' 

                        )
                    );
                    if(array_key_exists('body', $results)) $data = json_decode($results['body']);
                    if(array_key_exists('results',$data) && count($data->results)>0){
                        $id = $db->fetchAll(
                            'Select id from enderecos where endereco like ? ;'
                            ,array($data->results[0]->formatted_address)
                        );
                        if(empty($id)){
                             $db->fetchAll(
                                '
                                 INSERT INTO `enderecos`(`endereco`) select ? from dual
                                 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT endereco FROM enderecos WHERE endereco = ?); 
                                 INSERT INTO `geocodes`(`latlng`, `id_endereco`) SELECT  ? , (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()) from dual
                                 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT latlng FROM geocodes WHERE latlng = ?);
                                '
                                 ,array($data->results[0]->formatted_address, $data->results[0]->formatted_address, $latlng,$latlng)
                             );
                        }else{
                            $db->fetchAll(
                                'INSERT INTO `geocodes`(`latlng`, `id_endereco`) select  ? , ? from dual
                                 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT latlng FROM geocodes WHERE latlng = ?)'
                                ,array( $latlng, $id[0]['enderecos']['id'], $latlng )
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    return $data;//->results[0]->formatted_address

                }
                else{
                    return null;
                }
        }
        public function save(){

        }
    }
    ?>
```

Entretanto ao colocar ela numa das funções de um outro Controller, deixa o script muito lento gerando um Error `502 Bad Gateway` na página. O controller é o seguinte:

**Uma função de um dos controller que usá o GeocodeController**

```
[...]
public function getRelatorioRotas(){
    // Declarando classes
    $fun = new Functions();
    $GEO = new GeocodesController;
    // obtendo dados da requisição
    $data = $this->request->data;
        // contador de pontos
        if($data['dtFim'] == null){
            $count = $this->Record->query("
                Select Count(*) as total FROM  `records` 
                WHERE  `hour` >= ".$data['dtInicio']." 
                AND `vehicle_id` = ".$data['veiculo']." 
                ORDER BY `records`.`hour` asc
            "); 
        }else{
            $count = $this->Record->query("
                Select Count(*) as total FROM  `records` 
                WHERE  `hour` >= ".$data['dtInicio']." 
                AND `hour` <= ".$data['dtFim']." 
                AND `vehicle_id` = ".$data['veiculo']." 
                ORDER BY `records`.`hour` asc
            ");
        }
        $count = $count[0][0]['total'];
    if($count>0){
        // Instancia de variaveis
            // variavel paginas e tempo
            $i=$inicial=$distancia=$chega=0;
            $final=20;
            // Ponto Final e Endereço
             $PontoFinal=$PontoInicial=$LastPonto=$dt=null;
            // variavel de retorno dos pontos
            $rotas = $rota = array();
            $velMed = $velMax = $contadorRotas = 0;
            $menor=true;
            if($data['dtFim'] == null){
                $query = $this->Record->query(
                    "SELECT 
                    lat, lng, `ignition`, `hour`, `speed`
                    FROM  `records` 
                    WHERE  `hour` >= ".$data['dtInicio']." 
                    AND `vehicle_id` = ".$data['veiculo']."
                    ORDER BY `records`.`hour` asc
                    "
                );
            }else{
                $query = $this->Record->query(
                    "SELECT 
                    lat, lng, `ignition`, `hour`, `speed`
                    FROM  `records` 
                    WHERE  `hour` >= ".$data['dtInicio']." 
                    AND `hour` <= ".$data['dtFim']." 
                    AND `vehicle_id` = ".$data['veiculo']."
                    ORDER BY `records`.`hour` asc
                    "
                );

            }
                $count = count($query)-1;
                foreach ($query as $key => $record) {
                    $latlng = $record['records']['lat'].",".$record['records']['lng'];
                    if( $record['records']['speed'] > $velMax){
                        $velMax =  $record['records']['speed'];
                    }
                    $velMed+=$record['records']['speed'];
                    if( count($rota) <= 0 || $PontoInicial == null ) {
                            $dt = $GEO->geocode($latlng);

                            $PontoInicial = array(
                                'endereco' => $dt['endereco'],
                                'hour' => $record['records']['hour']
                            );
                            if($PontoFinal!=null && ( ($record['records']['hour'] - $PontoFinal['ponto']['hour'])<= (3*60*60))){    
                                array_push($rota, array(
                                    'latlng' => $PontoFinal['ponto']['latlng'],
                                    'ignition' => $PontoFinal['ponto']['ignition'],
                                    'speed' => $PontoFinal['ponto']['speed'],
                                    'hour' => $record['records']['hour']
                                ));
                            }
                            $obj = array(
                                'latlng' => $latlng,
                                'ignition' => $record['records']['ignition'],
                                'speed' => $record['records']['speed'],
                                'hour' => $record['records']['hour']
                            );
                            array_push($rota, $obj);
                        $distancia = 0;
                    }
                    else if( 
                             $record['records']['ignition']==true 
                             && ($record['records']['hour'] - $LastPonto['hour']) < 600
                    ) {
                        $ola = $fun->calcDistancia($LastPonto['lat'], $LastPonto['lng'], $record['records']['lat'], $record['records']['lng']);
                        $distancia += $ola;

                        if($ola > 0.01 &&  end($rota)['hour'] <= $record['records']['hour']){
                            $obj = array(
                                'latlng' => $latlng,
                                'ignition' => $record['records']['ignition'],
                                'speed' => $record['records']['speed'],
                                'hour' => $record['records']['hour'],
                                'distancia_do_ultimo_ponto' => $ola
                            );
                            array_push($rota, $obj);
                        }
                    }else {
                        if($key >= $count &&  end($rota)['hour'] <= $record['records']['hour']){
                            $ola = $fun->calcDistancia($LastPonto['lat'], $LastPonto['lng'], $record['records']['lat'], $record['records']['lng']);
                            $distancia += $ola;
                                $obj = array(
                                    'latlng' => $latlng,
                                    'ignition' => $record['records']['ignition'],
                                    'speed' => $record['records']['speed'],
                                    'hour' => $record['records']['hour'],
                                    'distancia_do_ultimo_ponto' => $ola
                                );
                            $ultimoPonto = $obj;
                        }else{
                            $ultimoPonto = end($rota);
                        }   

                            //$dt = $GEO->geocode($ultimoPonto['latlng']);
                            $PontoFinal = array(
                                'endereco' => $dt['endereco'],
                                'hour' => $ultimoPonto['hour']
                            );
                            $velMed /= (count($rota));
                            if($PontoFinal['hour'] != $PontoInicial['hour']){
                                $dur = $PontoFinal['hour'] - $PontoInicial['hour'];
                                if($dur > 60 && $distancia >0 && count($rota) >=4){
                                    if(count($rotas)>0){
                                        $ultima = end($rotas);
                                        $ultima = end($ultima['Pontos']);
                                        $oux = $rota[0];
                                        $diferenca = (int)$rota[0]['hour'] - (int)$ultima['hour'];
                                        if($diferenca < (600)){
                                            $nova=false;
                                            $contadorRotas--;
                                            $ultima=array_pop($rotas);
                                            if($ultima['velocidadeMaxima']>$velMax){
                                                $velMax = $ultima['velocidadeMaxima'];
                                            }
                                            foreach ($rota as $value) {
                                                array_push($ultima['Pontos'], $value);
                                            }   

                                            array_push($rotas, array(
                                                'id'=> $contadorRotas,
                                                'pontoInicial'=>$ultima['pontoInicial'], 
                                                'Pontos' => $ultima['Pontos'], 
                                                'pontoFinal'=> $PontoFinal,
                                                'distancia'=>$ultima['distancia']+$distancia,
                                                'duracao'=> $ultima['duracao']+$dur,
                                                'velocidadeMaxima'=> $velMax,
                                                'velocidadeMedia'=> ($ultima['velocidadeMedia']+$velMed)/2
                                            ));

                                        }else{
                                            $nova = true;
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        $nova = true;
                                    }
                                    if($nova){
                                        array_push($rotas, array(
                                            'id'=> $contadorRotas,
                                            'pontoInicial'=>$PontoInicial, 
                                            'Pontos' => $rota, 
                                            'pontoFinal'=> $PontoFinal,
                                            'distancia'=>$distancia,
                                            'duracao'=> $dur,
                                            'velocidadeMaxima'=> $velMax,
                                            'velocidadeMedia'=> $velMed
                                        ));
                                    }
                                    $contadorRotas++;
                                }
                            }
                            $PontoFinal['ponto'] = $rota[count($rota)-1];

                            $distancia = $velMed = $velMax = 0;
                            $PontoInicial=null;
                            $rota=array();
                    }
                    $LastPonto = $record['records'];
                }
                if(count($rotas)>0){            
                    $this->set('response', array('code'=>1,'rotas'=>$rotas, 'dataInicial'=> $data['dtInicio']));
                }else{
                    $this->set('response', array('code'=>0, 'rotas'=>$rotas, 'dataInicial'=> $data['dtInicio']));
                }
    }   
    else{
        $this->set('response', array('code'=>0));
    }

}
[...]
```

Se eu comentar a linha `$dt = $GEO->geocode($latlng);` o script funciona perfeitamente.

Toda via, para razões de debug comecei a comentar o Controller do Geocodee e printar por etapas. E verifiquei que estava dando conflito no insert das tabelas por causa das unique key, coisa que tinha resolvido com um `Insert Select` com clausula WHERE para verificar se existia, mas não esta funcionando. Depois disso verifiquei que o erro não ocorria com a mesma coordenada ou endereço duas vezes. Até o momento estou sem solução.

Comment: Escreva no campo resposta a resposta que você encontrou =] Assim isso poderá ajudar demais pessoas. Também não é considerado bem visto colocar "resolvido" no título, o ideal seria marcar a resposta que de fato resolveu seu problema

Comment: Coloque a resposta no campo de resposta abaixo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/248697/3

Comment: Obrigado, não conheço muito das normalizações do stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUÇÂO ENCONTRADA**

Notei que estava realizando varias requisições por segundo ao google, o que estourava o limite deles, entretanto tais requisições não eram necessárias visto que só precisava dos endereços final e inicial de cada rota. Então fiz outro foreach no final do script para buscar os endereço conforme segue abaixo:

Dentro do antigo foreach troquei as seguintes linhas:

```
[...]
//  $dt = $GEO->geocode($latlng);
$PontoInicial = array(
    'endereco' => $latlng,
    'hour' => $record['records']['hour']
);  
[...]
```

E acrescentei o seguinte foreach:

```
            foreach ($rotas as $K => $V) {
                $rotas[$K]['pontoFinal']['endereco'] = $GEO->geocode($rotas[$K]['pontoFinal']['endereco']);
                $rotas[$K]['pontoFinal']['endereco'] = $rotas[$K]['pontoFinal']['endereco']['endereco'];
                $rotas[$K]['pontoInicial']['endereco'] = $GEO->geocode($rotas[$K]['pontoInicial']['endereco']);
                $rotas[$K]['pontoInicial']['endereco'] = $rotas[$K]['pontoInicial']['endereco']['endereco'];
            }
```